# Why copy-list-initialization and copy-initialization behave differently for this case?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-initialization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class testClass {
    public:

    // testClass(const char * s)
    // {
    //     std::cout<<"custom constructor 1 called"<<std::endl;
    // }
    testClass(std::string s) : str(s)
    {
        std::cout<<"custom constructor 2 called"<<std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string str;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    testClass t0{"str"};
    testClass t2 = {"string"};
    testClass t4 = "string"; // error conversion from 'const char [7]' to non-scalar type 'testClass' requested

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that copy-initialization disallows implicit conversion from `const char *` to `string` while copy-list-initialization and direct-initialization allow for it.

Comment: Found the part answer on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization
and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor that the compiler is looking for is:

```
testClass(const char* s) : str(s) 
{
    std::cout << "custom constructor 3 called" << std::endl;
}
```

I think your code fails because it would need two implicit conversions, assignment and `const char*` to `const std::string&`.

Additionally you should use `const std::string&` instead.

```
testClass(const std::string &s) : str(s)
{
    std::cout<<"custom constructor 2 called"<<std::endl;
}
```

Because in `testClass t4 = "string";` you are giving a `const char*`.